# Can I apply click event on body element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am willing to create div's dynamically on double clicking anywhere on the page. Can I apply click event to body element?

Here's what I tried so far:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function(){ 
    alert("click"); 
    jQuery("body").dblclick(function(event){ 
        alert("click"); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Eh, yes... Why not just try it? Edit: do mind that all events bubble up to body unless told otherwise ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
// Example, needs some IE compatibility work
document.body.ondblclick = function (evt) {
    createNewDiv(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
}
```

Is there something you tried that didn't work?

---

Responding to your comment,

> *"can you tell me whats wrong with this one"*
>
> ```
> jQuery("document").ready(function(){ alert("click"); jQuery("body").dblclick(function(event){ alert("click"); }); });
> ```

The problem is you're using a tag selector to look for the document object.  `jQuery("document")` will look for an element in the document called `<document>`, which doesn't exist.  You need to just pass in the document object, so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert("click"); 
    jQuery("body").dblclick(function(event){ 
        alert("click"); 
    }); 
});
```

Also, by default a `<body>` element is only as big as its content, so if you apply the `dblclick` event to a `<body>` with no content, only the top-left part of the document will fire the event.  Instead, you want to apply it to the `document` object instead:

```
jQuery(document).dblclick(function(event){ 
    alert("click"); 
});
```

> **Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4DKC/2/**

Comment: jQuery("document").ready(function(){
alert("click");

jQuery("body").dblclick(function(event){
alert("click");
});

}); can you tell me whats wrong with this one.

Comment: @sushil: see my updated answer for an explanation as to why that's not working

Comment: i modified it still. Still it doesnt gives the alert on the dbl click in the body. I have also created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a4DKC/1/